# Gulp multiple tasks to same destination failing

Tags: handlebars.js, gulp

Having trouble understanding where I'm going wrong with this (if it's me at all), I've got my (first) gulp file, and it's working fine:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var del = require('del');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var handlebars = require('gulp-handlebars');
var wrap = require('gulp-wrap');
var declare = require('gulp-declare');

gulp.task('default', ['clean', 'minify-external', 'minify-internal']);

gulp.task('clean', function() {
    del(['build/js/'], function(err){ });
});

gulp.task('minify-external', function() {
    return gulp.src([
        'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
        'bower_components/handlebars/handlebars.js',
        'bower_components/ember/ember.js',
        'bower_components/ember-data/ember-data.js',
    ])
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(concat('scripts.min.js'))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js/'));
});

gulp.task('minify-internal', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/js/**/*.js')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(concat('lib.min.js'))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js//'));
});

gulp.watch('src/js/**/*.js', ['minify-internal']);
```

Next I'm trying to add the handlebars pre-compilation into it:

```
//above omitted for brevity
gulp.task('default', ['clean', 'minify-external', 'minify-internal']);

//...
gulp.task('templates', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/templates/**/*.hbs')
    .pipe(handlebars())
    .pipe(wrap('Handlebars.template(<%= contents %>)'))
    .pipe(declare({
        namespace: 'Todos.templates',
        noRedeclare: true, // Avoid duplicate declarations
    }))
    .pipe(concat('templates.min.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js/'));
});
```

And the script now fails:

```
Error: EEXIST, mkdir '[BUILD PATH]/build/js'
```

Seems to be specific to the `templates` task, as the other two `minify-x` tasks run fine. I've attempted async and sync running (that is removing the return statements from tasks). Am I missing something on how streams interact here? Is it normal to output from multiple tasks to the same folder?

Comment: Ran into a similar problem. If you found out anything new, please post an answer explaining your findings!

Comment: I see two forward slashes in one of your `dest` calls....

Comment: @JesperRønn-Jensen Afraid I never found a decent solution to this problem, originally I just started commenting out `sourcemaps`, but what I ended up doing is stop using sourcemaps entirely, and switched over to https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-usemin instead.